# Access storage connected to router from Modem ?

Tags: networking, router, usb, modem, storage

I have a Telus DSL connection provided through T3200M modem to which I have connected a TP-Link Archer C8 router. Most of my devices are connected to T3200M via ethernet or wifi while I have a USB drive plugged into the C8 and a device connected to C8 through wifi.

I would like to access the USB storage from all the devices regardless of whether they are connected to the modem or the router. I have tried searching for this on this forum and google but couldn't find anything relevant. May be I am not using the right keywords.

I thought it is possible to have devices connected to modem and router to be in the same address range meaning in the same network. Then, logically I should be able to access any computer within the network. The storage device itself would appear as an SMB share with an IP address still within the same network. Am I being silly to think this way ?

So, is it really possible or did I miss something here ? If it is possible, could someone point me at a guide that could help set it up ?

Thanks

Comment: "I would like to access the USB storage from all the devices regardless of whether they are connected to the modem or the router. " - This won't be possible.

Comment: what you are failing to consider is that your routers LAN and WAN sides are used very differently, and most of the time, with a consumer grade router, you cannot treat the WAN as a trusted network. If you are using an enterprise grade router, you could probably configure it, but most of those don't come with USB storage attachment, as enterprises have servers, and don't need to try to shoehorn all their services into a single device.